# Динамическое добавление формы на страницу

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form

Как реализовать динамическое добавление формы на страницу?
Допустим я создаю некий объект, который содержит блоки. Но я не знаю сколько блоков должно быть (на странице блоки - это формы для заполнения данных).
Как сделать кнопку, которая добавляет на страницу эту самую форму с полями для ввода?

Answer (score -1):

- Создаёте `partial` с формой
- Создаёте метод в контроллере
- В этот метод отправляете GET запрос `remote: true`
- В вашем `js.erb` рендерите `partial` с формой куда нужно.

Профит.